# Pagination will show first page, but not second or third

Tags: javascript, html, pagination

I'm trying to set up pagination for some blog posts. It works with the first page, and I check my tests to see if the loop is actually populating the "postsToDisplay" array (which it does), but when I click the second-page button, nothing shows up. I can click the first-page button and it brings the first page of posts back up. For some reason, it won't push the new arrays to the page though.

I've tried adding and taking away tests to see what is working. The array is definitely being populated, and the loop is going through the correct "i" values just fine.

Here's some edited code to reproduce my problem:

```
//Use this as "scripts.js"


$(document).ready(function() {
  var realBlog = document.getElementsByClassName("realBlog");
  var postsPerPage = 2;
  var $pagination = $(".pagination")

  function showPage(page) {
    $(realBlog).hide();
    let postsToDisplay = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < realBlog.length; i += 1) {
      if (i >= page * postsPerPage && i <= page * postsPerPage + postsPerPage - 1) {
        postsToDisplay.push(realBlog[i]);
        console.log(i); //Test to see if the loop is running the correct numbers
        $(postsToDisplay[i]).show();
      }
    }
    console.log(postsToDisplay); //Test to see if the array is full
    return postsToDisplay;
  }
  showPage(0);

  function createPageNumbers() {
    let createUl = document.createElement("ul");
    createUl.className = "pageNumbers";
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(realBlog.length/2); i += 1) {
      let createLi = document.createElement("li");
      let createA = document.createElement("a");
      createA.href = "#" + i;
      createA.textContent = i;
      createLi.className = "pageButton";
      createLi.append(createA);
      createUl.append(createLi);
      $(".pagination").append(createUl);
      createA.addEventListener("click", () => {
        showPage(i-1);
      });
    }
  }

  createPageNumbers();
});
```

```
//Use this as index.html


<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container realBlog">
      <h1 class="realBlogTitle threeDText">Title</h1>
      <p class="entry"></p>
      <div class="entryInfo">
        <span class="tag1"></span>
        <span class="tag2"></span>
        <span class="date"></span>
        <span class="time"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="borderBottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container realBlog">
      <h1 class="realBlogTitle threeDText">Title</h1>
      <p class="entry"></p>
      <div class="entryInfo">
        <span class="tag1"></span>
        <span class="tag2"></span>
        <span class="date"></span>
        <span class="time"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="borderBottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container realBlog">
      <h1 class="realBlogTitle threeDText">Title</h1>
      <p class="entry"></p>
      <div class="entryInfo">
        <span class="tag1"></span>
        <span class="tag2"></span>
        <span class="date"></span>
        <span class="time"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="borderBottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Page 1 should show posts 1 and 2, page 2 should show post 3.

Comment: Can you create a [mre]? Also, you're mixing jQuery and vanilla JS all over the place.

Comment: Edited the post to include a way to reproduce my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the answer, and of course, it's a silly mistake. I have this little snippet: `$(postsToDisplay[i]).show();`

I'm not sure why I'm trying to show each 'i' when I can just show the whole array... So the fix is `$(postsToDisplay).show();`